# Try catch trouble in netbeans

Tags: if-statement, netbeans, hashmap, try-catch

I'm trying to create a search engine that gets information from my SQL database. Right now I'm struggling to make the combobox and textfield work. So far I can only make the first part of the code work, it allows the user to search for a name in the database. The rest however doesn't work at all, resulting in just an empty window where the info should pop up.

Here are some translations of the Swedish words present in the code:

Namn - Name

sokt - Searched

ANSTALLD - Employee

Aid - Employee id

telefon - phone

```
try
{

if(jComboBoxSokAID.getSelectedItem().equals("Namn"))
{
    String namn = jTextFieldSokText.getText();
    String namnQuery = "select * from ANSTALLD where namn = '" + namn + "'";
    try
    {
        HashMap <String, String> soktNamn = idb.fetchRow(namnQuery);
        jTextAreaSpecialistInfo.setText("Namn: " + soktNamn.get("namn") + "\n" + "Aid: " + soktNamn.get ("aid") + "\n" + "Telefon: " + soktNamn.get ("telefon") + "\n" + "Mail: " + soktNamn.get ("mail"));
        if(jComboBoxSokAID.getSelectedItem().equals("Mail"))
        {
        String mail = jTextFieldSokText.getText();
        String mailQuery = "select * from ANSTALLD where mail = '" + mail + "'";
        try
        {
            HashMap <String, String> soktMail = idb.fetchRow(mailQuery);
            jTextAreaSpecialistInfo.setText("Namn: " + soktMail.get("namn") + "\n" + "Aid: " + soktMail.get ("aid") + "\n" + "Telefon: " + soktMail.get ("telefon") + "\n" + "Mail: " + soktMail.get ("mail"));

            if(jComboBoxSokAID.getSelectedItem().equals("Telefon"))
            {    
            String telefon = jTextFieldSokText.getText();
            String telefonQuery = "select * from ANSTALLD where telefon = '" + telefon + "'";
            try
            {
                HashMap <String, String> soktTelefon = idb.fetchRow(telefonQuery);
                jTextAreaSpecialistInfo.setText("Namn: " + soktTelefon.get("namn") + "\n" + "Aid: " + soktTelefon.get ("aid") + "\n" + "Telefon: " + soktTelefon.get ("telefon") + "\n" + "Mail: " + soktTelefon.get ("mail"));

                if(jComboBoxSokAID.getSelectedItem().equals("AID"))
                {    
                String AID = jTextFieldSokText.getText();
                String AIDQuery = "select * from ANSTALLD where aid = '" + AID + "'";
                try
                {
                HashMap <String, String> soktAID = idb.fetchRow(AIDQuery);           
                jTextAreaSpecialistInfo.setText("Namn: " + soktAID.get("namn") + "\n" + "Aid: " + soktAID.get ("aid") + "\n" + "Telefon: " + soktAID.get ("telefon") + "\n" + "Mail: " + soktAID.get ("mail"));

                }

                catch (InformatikException e)
                {
                    if(jComboBoxSokAID == null)
                    jTextAreaSpecialistInfo.setText("Sökningen gav inga resultat");
                }

                }

            }

            catch (InformatikException e)
            {

            }

            }


        }
            catch (InformatikException e)
            {

            }
        }

    }
    catch (InformatikException e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Why you tagged JavaScript when you only using Java in your code example?

Answer (score 0):

Don't write code this way.

Never have empty catch blocks.

I prefer to have a single try/catch in a method.  Nesting them this way is an indication that you ought to refactor a method that's doing too much.

You've mingled persistence and UI code together in the worst way possible.  Tease them apart so you can test and use them separately.

You don't close any database resources.  This will come to grief.

Comment: Thank you mate! 

I'm thinking of splitting the search method into four different buttons, allowing me to not get this whole thing so jumbled.
Will still appreciate more comments from others!